# Why won't my php file insert data into my mysql database?

Tags: php, database-connection

I have been having trouble getting my PHP file to insert data into my database.  I have gone so far as making one simple script to put data into my database and it still isn't working.  I'm hoping that someone will see something that will make me feel like a dork for having missed it.  The code below is what is in my simple script that isn't inserting into my database.

```
<? php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","user","password","database"

mysql_query($con,"INSERT INTO table_name (username, pass) VALUES ('bob', 'tom')");

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I hope that you guys see the problem because I'm drawing a complete blank.

Comment: Are any error or status codes returned?

Comment: You have a syntax error, mysql_connect doesn't have a closing parenthesis or a semicolon at the end of the line

Comment: +1 on the parenthesis/semicolon, but also use mysqli. mysql is deprecated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `mysql_select_db("yourdatabase", $con);`

Edit: forget that, you have it in your connection, but like someone commented, you have a syntax error.

You can also use [mysql_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to see what's going wrong.

P.s. the use of the old mysql extension is highly discouraged.

Comment: Thanks guys, I added the missing parenthesis and semicolon and changed it to mysqli_query. Didn't help.  And I'm not throwing any errors.  I was told that adding the database to be selected to the end of my connection was legit. Not so much? Either way, adding mysql_select_db didn't solve my issue. I added $check = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO members (username, pass) VALUES ("bob", "tom")");
$result=mysqli_query($check);
if (mysqli_errno()){
 echo "MySQL error ".mysql_errno().": " . mysql_error() ."\n when executing $check"; }  I still didn't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

IN the code that you posted, mysql_connect is missing the closing paren. Did you check and see if the SQL returns any errors by itself?

I just ran the query on my server, and it works-it inserts the row. So, there's nothing wrong with your query. Are you sure you have the table set up properly? What kind of fields are username and password in your table? Are you using the correct table name? Are you sure that you're checking in the same table that you're writing to?

Answer (score 0):

```
<? php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","user","password","database"
```

Correct syntax and procedure is to connect,select the database.. But make sure that you have closed off your functions :

```
$con = mysql_connect("host","user","password");
$Database = mysql_select_db("Database",$con);
```